# How to enable the circle keyboard of the Gear S2

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy-gear

I wrote a web app for the Samsung Gear S2 with HTML and JS. I can enter text and numbers with the T9 keyboard. But it doesn't work fine, because everything is very small.
But I saw a circle keyboard in (Settings - LogScreen - LogScreen - PIN) were you can enter 4 numbers with a great looking keyboard.
Just like this: [image: Circle keyboard on Gear S2]
Now, I want to use this one, but I don't find a name for this keyboard neither for the possibility to get access on this one.

Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a native application control. You can find it in the Online Samples as (Circle) Dialer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have to look to implement it, so it works in my web app. Perhaps I'll create a hybrid app...